# Can Android apps automatically receive push notification content when it's delivered while the app is in foreground?

Tags: android, push-notification

I'm an iOS developer and this behavior is natural in iOS. If the app is in foreground and there's push notification for the app, the app will receive the push notification content instead of the OS create push notification in the notification center. Now I want to help my fellow Android developer to do the same, but we don't know where to look. As far as he knows, Android app will never receive push notification unless the user tap on the push notification, even if the app is in foreground. We need this so we can refresh the chat screen when we receive push notification from the server that a new chat message is coming. Can this behavior emulated in Android? All this time, the way he retrieved new chat message is that every 5 seconds he queries the server for new messages.

Comment: For people voting negative and voting to close, I believe this question has a very simple answer, but the answer is drowned in the advanced Q&A about push notification that we simply can't find it. Our native language is not english, so a little compassion, a little answer, and a little time, works a long way. We can research it ourselves after we know what the keyword to look for.

Comment: @MarcinOrlowski well, I'm not familiar with firebase, let alone for android. I have tried with multiple queries, but the more query I search, the weirder the result. I really understand the solution for this question will be very simple, but this link that explains about background foreground state never comes up in my search.

Comment: @MarcinOrlowski link like this is what's comes up in my search: https://pusher.com/tutorials/push-notifications-android/

Comment: I gave you precise link to the page to read. No need to search too much for now. And Pusher is 3rd party alternative to FCM

Comment: The answer is yes. For details, you need to read about push notification like FCM in the link @MarcinOrlowski provided.

Comment: @MarcinOrlowski yes, we're now developing the solution from the link. The link made him realize that the data for push notification when the app is in foreground state has been there all along.